# Android LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation() returns null

Tags: android, gps

So I'm trying to sample the gps coordinates just once in an application.  I don't want to create a LocationListener object to constantly get gps updates.  I want to wait until receiving the coordinates, and then proceed on to another task.

Here is a code snippet

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)act.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria crit = new Criteria();
crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(crit, true);
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

The loc variable is always null in the emulator.  I tried using the command "geo fix latitude longitude" to set it, and also I tried using the DDMS way of setting it.  Neither method had any effect on the code.  Also the snippet isn't causing any exceptions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's a nice example with source code [http://marakana.com/forums/android/android_examples/42.html](http://marakana.com/forums/android/android_examples/42.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The call to request update for a location is not blocking, hence it wont wait there. Also the provider in emulator may not have been started.

A possible check could be to see if the settings in it disable gps provider ? then send geo fix.

However, I would use Location Listener, it would be ideal in your case since you need a geo fix to proceed further.Location Listener is Used for receiving notifications from the LocationManager when the location has changed. You can unregister the listener after first geofix.

Note: It can take some time on device to get current location, and even on device this can return null.

Comment: Yeah, doing a LocationListener then waiting till you have a fix you're happy with is pretty much your only option. As mentioned, you can immediately unregister it.

Comment: It turns out that without any LocationListener it will not work.  Even just adding a mock LocationListener that doesn't even do anything will cause the phone to get gps coordinates.

Comment: I am assuming LocationListener updates some cached location, which locationManager uses. Thanks for posting.

Comment: you can also aimed for having a broadcast receiver and request the update with a PendingIntent

Comment: So if the method is called last known location, why cannot it return the last known location rather than waiting for a new fix. Seems very counter productive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html) , create a runnable that does what you need to do with that GPS location, and pass it to

```
boolean     runOnFirstFix(java.lang.Runnable runnable)
          Queues a runnable to be executed as soon as we have a location fix.
```

and then disable the location updates for the MyLocationOverlay.

Edit:  The reason the location is null is because at the time that code is run, no geofix has been received.

Comment: I get a null too, but the Google maps app know's where I am instantly so there must be some fix stored away somwwhere.

Comment: Using a runnable is clever but there's no need to bring in the google maps api for this problem.