# Why is location null?

Tags: android, location, locationmanager, google-geocoder

I'm trying to get my current location in my app using the code below:

```
    List<Address> adds = null;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    String bestProvider;

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    bestProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);


    if (location == null)
    {
         Toast.makeText(this,"Location Not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try 
        {
            users = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            lat=(double)users.get(0).getLatitude();
            lng=(double)users.get(0).getLongitude();
            System.out.println(" DDD lat: " +lat+",  longitude: "+lng);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But location keeps showing up as null, therefore the Location Not found message appears on app.  Am i missing something?

Manifest permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608632/android-locationmanager-getlastknownlocation-returns-null

Use the search feature next time!

Comment: Are you trying it in a device?

Comment: I am, it turns out that it was returning that the network was the best provider for location, but the devices setting at the time had network location services turned off, it was a weird one, but it works now.