# Android GPS is returning null location

Tags: android, gps

I have written code in that if GPS is disabled it will be enabled by code and try to get Location from gps but I am getting a null value.  Below is my code

```
   public void getValue() {
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) MySettings.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gpsEnabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    System.out.println("GPS IS "+gpsEnabled);
    if (!gpsEnabled) {
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if (!provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    try {
        getBatteryLevel();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, MySettings.this);
        Location location = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        mLocation = location;
        if (location != null) {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lon = location.getLongitude();
            address = getAddress();
            alt = location.getAltitude();
            if (meterFootFlag) {
                diameter = location.getAccuracy();
            } else
                diameter = location.getAccuracy() / 3.28084;
        } else {
            lat = 0.0;
            lon = 0.0;
            alt = 0.0;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        lat = 0.0;
        lon = 0.0;
        alt = 0.0;
    }
```

Also I have added permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

but I am getting a null value for the location.

Any ideas on how I can get the location?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1609593/1321873

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct just wait until GPs get altitude from a satellite it may take mroe than 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    public Location showLocation(){
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //Class model, save latitude and longitude
    NavegadorCoordenadas locate = new NavegadorCoordenadas();
    Criteria crit = new Criteria();
    crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    String provider = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);
    Location loc = getLastKnownLocation(lm);                    
    locate.setLatitude(loc.getLatitude()); 
    locate.setLongitude(loc.getLongitude());
    return loc;     
}

private Location getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager location) {
    List<String> providers = location.getProviders(true);
    Location bestLocation = null;
    for (String provider : providers) {
        Location l = location.getLastKnownLocation(provider);           
        if (l == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {             
            bestLocation = l;
        }
    }
    if (bestLocation == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return bestLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are checking on `DEVICE` only.. In Emulator it will give Null Values for `GPS` as it is running in the system so it doesnot have permission for `GPS`

Answer (score 0):

```
locationMangaer = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }

    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 10,
            locationListener);
```

Now make **MyLocationListener class** in same activity.

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            String longitude = "Longitude: " +loc.getLongitude();  
            String latitude = "Latitude: " +loc.getLatitude();

            /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */
            String cityName=null;                 
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());                  
            List<Address>  addresses;  
            try {  
             addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);  
             if (addresses.size() > 0) { 
              System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());  
             cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();  
                System.out.println("MESSAGE:"+cityName);
             }
            } catch (IOException e) {                 
             e.printStackTrace();  
            } 

            String s = longitude+"\n"+latitude+"\t city name:"+cityName;
                Log.v("OUTPUT, s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }
}
```

Run your application in **Actual device**.

you can figure out that automatic start **GPS** and see **console** logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to open Permissions through the 
Settings--> Applications-->YourApp-->permissions 
And another reason could be delay, it takes time to connect to network, somethimes more than a minute